# A function whose derivatives belong to $BMO(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am reading the paper "Bounded Mean Oscillation and Sobolev Spaces" by Robert
s. Strichartz, Indiana University Mathematics Journal , 1980, Vol. 29, pp.
539-558. In this paper he defines the space $I_{\alpha}(BMO)$ as the image of
$BMO(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ under the Riesz potential
$$
I_{\alpha}f=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\xi|^{-\alpha}\mathcal{F}(f)),
$$
the Riesz potential being defined on tempered distributions modulo polynomials
of degree $\leq\alpha$. For $\alpha=1$ he states that $f\in I_{1}(BMO)$ if and
only if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}\in BMO(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for every
$i=1,\ldots,n$.

In Theorem 3.3 he proves that $f\in I_{1}(BMO)$ if and only if $f$ is of
temperate growth and
$$
\sup_{Q_{s}}\left(  \frac{1}{|Q_{s}|}\int_{Q_{s}}\int_{|y|\leq s}
\frac{|f(x+y)-2f(x)+f(x+y)|^{2}}{|x-y|^{n+2}}dydx\right)  ^{1/2}<\infty.
$$
In the proof he does not show that if $f\in I_{1}(BMO)$, then  $f$ is of
temperate growth, which I assume means that $f$ is bounded in absolute value
by a polynomial. I don't see an easy way to prove this. Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: This follows from the fact that for all $\alpha>0$, one can check that the chain of continuous inclusions $$BMO^{-\alpha}\subset \dot{\mathrm{B}}^{-\alpha}_{\infty,\infty}\subset\mathcal{S}'.$$

Comment: Do you have a reference with a valid proof? In "Tempered homogeneous function spaces," Triebel defines all these spaces as spaces of tempered distributions.  In "Theory of functions spaces", he takes all these spaces in $Z'$, which is defined as $\mathcal{S}'$ modulo polynomial. All I know is that $f$ is locally integrable, so it is a distribution but I don't see why it is a tempered distribution.

Comment: or the sum of a tempered distribution and a polynomial. This is what I would need to prove. I thought about the homogeneous Zygmund class, but all the inequalities (to prove that they are almost Lipschitz) I know only work for bounded functions.

Comment: As a complete normed vector space $BMO$ itself is no longer a space of distribution, and it cannot be. There is this paper by Bourdaud about it.

Comment: Proposition 1.31, from Dimitri Cobb's PhD Thesis, p.69. The same argument would apply for $BMO^{-\alpha}$ for any $\alpha>0$ !

Comment: The thesis is entitled "Étude mathématique de fluides en interaction avec un champ
magnétique", but don't be afraid the core content is in English.

Comment: Wait, I did realized that I misread your post now. What I gave to you is absolutely not what you were looking for, sorry.

Comment: One can check $BMO^{1}=(\mathcal{H}^{-1,1})'$ where $$\lVert u \rVert_{\mathcal{H}^{-1,1}}=\lVert (-\Delta)^{-\frac{1}{2}}u \rVert_{\mathcal{H}^{1}}(\simeq \lVert u \rVert_{\dot{\mathrm{F}}^{-1}_{1,2}})$$.
Thus, by
$$\dot{\mathrm{B}}^{-1}_{1,1}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{H}^{-1,1} \hookrightarrow \dot{\mathrm{B}}^{-1}_{1,2}.$$
It follows by duality
$$\dot{\mathrm{B}}^{1}_{\infty,2}\hookrightarrow BMO^1 \hookrightarrow \dot{\mathrm{B}}^{1}_{\infty,\infty}.$$

Then, we need to check it for $\dot{\mathrm{B}}^{1}_{\infty,\infty}$.

The result follows by Thm 2.31 from Sawano's book p.284.

Comment: This would imply that every continuous function such that $$|f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)|\le C|h|$$ has polynomial growth. I was not able to find a direct proof of this fact.